# Simple time and work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a car production factory, 3 men took 5 days to produce 5 car. Given that, all the men work at the same rate, how many more days would it take for 15 men to produce 64 cars?

The solution is given in my book, however I can't wrap my head around it.

Can someone please solve this in an easy and concise way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If 3 men take 5 days for 5 cars, then 3 men take 1 day for 1 car. Thus 15 men would take 1/5 day for one car. And hence for 64 cars these 15 men would need 64/5 days, which is 12.8 days.

Comment: The answer is shown to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

number of cars produced per day per men are $\frac{5}{3\cdot 5}=\frac{1}{3}$ since 5 cars have been  produced in 5 days hence remaining 59 cars will be produced say in d more days by 15 men then $$\frac13\cdot 15\cdot d=59$$ 
$$d=11.8 days$$
hope this helps you